# Android SQlite Database storing to phone's memory and retrieving

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm relatively new to android and databases. I'm developing an app where I store all the details in database entered by user. When user enters all the details I want to give an option to save this entire database. When he comes back to the app he must be able to either create a new database or open the previously stored one. I checked lot of articles but I'm not quite sure about it. Any help is welcome. I have posted my database program below.

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_INFO = "info";
public static final String COLUMN_ID1 = "_id1";
public static final String COLUMN_PLAYER = "player";
public static final String COLUMN_RUNSSCORED = "runsscored";
public static final String COLUMN_BALLSFACED = "ballsfaced";
public static final String COLUMN_WICKETS = "wickets";

public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String query1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCOREINFO + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PLAYER + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_RUNSSCORED + " INTEGER, " +
            COLUMN_BALLSFACED + " INTEGER, " +
            COLUMN_WICKETS +  " INTEGER " + ");";
    db.execSQL(query1);
}
```

And I have written corresponding row adding code also. Now when the user clicks the particular button this database must be stored in the memory and later if the user wishes to enter the new details then how do I create new database and if he wishes to open previously stored data, how to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

First, most people using a static database name and version simplify their `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor like this:

```
public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

`DATABASE_NAME` is the name of the database file on the filesystem (specifically, in the `databases` directory of your app's data directory). This means the code above always opens the same database file. If that's all you want, then you're done.

If you actually want separate database files, then you need to allow different database names, for example:

```
public DBHandler(Context context, String dbName) {
    super(context, dbName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```